# How to convert a Tableau extract data to csv (or xls)

Tags: tableau-api

I have successfully converted from a Tableau `.twbx` file to `.twb` and now have a `.tde` file for the data.  How can this `.tde` be converted to either `.csv` or `.xls(x)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also export to CSV from the Data menu starting in version 10.3.

That command exports the entire data source, while the export commands on the worksheet menu export only the data referenced by the worksheet. Both are useful. One exports the entire data source, the other exports the fields used on the worksheet

*Note to readers* : See my answers below with screenshots on how to do this.

Comment: Please add a screenshot and instructions : i could not find that option

Comment: I added the details in an add-on answer. Will upvote your answer for providing direction : reasonably you could do likewise for mine.

Comment: Ok, but it would have been simpler for future readers to edit one answer rather than create 2 separate ones

Comment: From the future to the past: Alex yes I agree. In the intervening years I have been doing just as you say: to augment an existing answer if it were already  heading the same  direction.  At the time I had thought that editing others' answers were impolite.   I have switched the "award" over to you as a recognition

Answer (score 1):

The `Worksheet | Export | Data (or Crosstab to Excel)' appear to have done the trick: there are now an`xlsx`and a`.csv` file with the relevant dataset included.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on @AlexBlakemore 's answer:  from Version `10.2.2` there is a feature for `Export to CSV`.  It is non intuitive how to find it: select the `Data | (data source name) | Export to CSV` :

[image]