# Tableau file saving options

Tags: tableau-api

I am pretty new to tableau. I know tableau has desktop version and tableau server and we have different file options to save file. I needs some help on understanding these file saving options. appreciate any help !

Q1: will file saving  options stay same between desktop version and server version .

Q2: File type options: 
I am clear on 
1. workbook (.twb) store visualization without source data
2. data source (.tds) store information required to access data source, store link to data source without visualization

but have doubts on these file type options: 
3. what is  bookmark (.tbm) option ?
4. workbook package : what is the difference between workbook package and workbook ? looks like workbook package cannot save data source information but can save extracted data?

5. data extract(.tde) 
   when saving data as a data extract, I should choose  connection type as extract not live?  what should I do if I have 1000 rows and 100 columns in my data source, but  only want  500 rows and 50 columns to be extracted  in a csv file?

Comment: Have you read the help documents on the different file types?

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from Tableau's Online Help Section. I would advise visiting their online help section for links to a more detailed description of each file type, if needed.

You can save your work using several different Tableau specific file types: workbooks, bookmarks, packaged data files, data extracts, and data connection files. Each of these file types are described below. For related details, see Save Your Work.

• Workbooks (.twb) – Tableau workbook files have the .twb file extension. Workbooks hold one or more worksheets, plus zero or more dashboards and stories.

• Bookmarks (.tbm) – Tableau bookmark files have the .tbm file extension. Bookmarks contain a single worksheet and are an easy way to quickly share your work. For more information, see Save a bookmark.

• Packaged Workbooks (.twbx) – Tableau packaged workbooks have the .twbx file extension. A packaged workbook is a single zip file that contains a workbook along with any supporting local file data and background images. This format is the best way to package your work for sharing with others who don’t have access to the original data. For more information, see Packaged Workbooks.

• Extract (.hyper or .tde) – Depending on the version the extract was created in, Tableau extract files can have either the .hyper or .tde file extension. Extract files are a local copy of a subset or entire data set that you can use to share data with others, when you need to work offline, and improve performance. For more information, see Extract Your Data.

• Data Source (.tds) – Tableau data source files have the .tds file extension. Data source files are shortcuts for quickly connecting to the original data that you use often. Data source files do not contain the actual data but rather the information necessary to connect to the actual data as well as any modifications you've made on top of the actual data such as changing default properties, creating calculated fields, adding groups, and so on. For more information, see Save Data Sources.

• Packaged Data Source (.tdsx) – Tableau packaged data source files have the .tdsx file extension. A packaged data source is a zip file that contains the data source file (.tds) described above as well as any local file data such as extract files (.hyper or .tde), text files, Excel files, Access files, and local cube files. Use this format to create a single file that you can then share with others who may not have access to the original data stored locally on your computer. For more information, see Save Data Sources.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sufficient rep to reply as a comment on G. Roup's answer, but I'll try to piggy back on their excellent answer. Click [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/environ_filesandfolders.html) to go directly to the Tableau help section G. Roup refers to. Additionally, [this Tableau forum thread](https://community.tableau.com/thread/236599) ("How to publish .twb files") may help.

TWBX files (i.e., package workbooks) include both the data extract and data source information. These will tend to have the largest file size (they can be unwieldy if you don't design your extract intelligently) but they are often most flexible because, as G. Roup and the Tableau help section note, the user doesn't need access to or permissions for the database in question. On Tableau Server, you can upload an extract workbook and schedule a refresh cycle for the extract so that users always get a fresh copy. Generally, you will need to use embedded credentials for this.

TWB files (i.e., workbooks) either separate the extract from the data source or else use a live connection. If you upload these to Tableau server then you will generally have to use a live database connection. This might be bad if your server is slow or you have a lot of users trying to hit the database at the same time.

Per your point #5, this is actually several totally separate questions from your main question:

- If you have gone to the trouble of creating an extract, you will generally want to use it as opposed to a live connection (unless it is stale).
- If you only want a subset of the data, you can use the filters ([see this Tableau help article](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_datasource.html) "Filter Data from Your Data Source" for more) or if your data source uses a custom SQL query, you can add WHERE clauses to your query.
- If you then want to pipe your extract out as a CSV, check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612508/how-to-convert-a-tableau-extract-data-to-csv-or-xls). In short, Data > [your data source] > Export Data to CSV.